# What is the ASP.NET attribute to call "On Registration Error" for Custom Errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

When using the prebuilt Membership features in ASP.NET (i.e. the Login.aspx, Register.aspx, etc...), I can create custom error messages using the following in my ASP.NET Login page in the asp:Login element (notice the OnLoginError attribute which calls my code-behind method).

```
<asp:Login ID="LoginBlock" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled" RenderOuterTable="false" OnLoginError="LoginBlock_LoginError">
```

Is there such an attribute in the prebuilt Register.aspx page? If so, which registration HTML element would it go into? I've been looking on SO and through the Intellisense prompts and I'm not seeing what it would be.

Here is my Registration page from the Content element down:

```
<asp:Content ID="bodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="dashboardBody" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/dcfpakHelper.js"></script>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeout="1200" EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnableCdn="true" />
    <asp:CreateUserWizard runat="server" ID="RegisterUser" ViewStateMode="Disabled" OnCreatedUser="RegisterUser_CreatedUser" OnRegistrationError="">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="wizardStepPlaceholder" />
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="navigationPlaceholder" />
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <WizardSteps>
            <asp:CreateUserWizardStep runat="server" ID="RegisterUserWizardStep">
                <ContentTemplate>


                    <p class="validation-summary-errors">
                        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ErrorMessage" />
                    </p>

                    <fieldset class="form-signin">
                        <legend>Registration Form</legend>

                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" CssClass="sr-only" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Email">Email address</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Email" ID="Email" TextMode="Email" OnTextChanged="SetUserNameTextToEmailText" />
                        <div style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email"
                            CssClass="field-validation-error text-center alert alert-danger" ErrorMessage="The email address field is required." />
                        </div>


                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" CssClass="sr-only" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Password" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" />
                        <div style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px">
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password"
                            CssClass="field-validation-error text-center alert alert-danger" ErrorMessage="The password field is required." />
                        </div>


                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" CssClass="sr-only" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ConfirmPassword">Confirm password</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" runat="server" ID="ConfirmPassword" TextMode="Password" />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword"
                            CssClass="field-validation-error" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="The confirm password field is required." />
                        <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToCompare="Password" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword"
                            CssClass="field-validation-error" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="The password and confirmation password do not match." />

                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" CssClass="sr-only" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User name</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" placeholder="User Name" runat="server" ID="UserName" style="display: none"/>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
                            CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The user name field is required." />

                        <div style="padding-top: 20px">
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-block" runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext" Text="Register" />
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <CustomNavigationTemplate />
            </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
        </WizardSteps>
    </asp:CreateUserWizard>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some work, I figured it out (ironically, it was an answer written in VB.NET that got me on the right path. See the post on this site [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1167849.aspx?Show%20custom%20message%20in%20CreateUserWizard%20ErrorMessage%20control). It's under XiaoYong Dai's answer).

In the CreateUserWizard element, I inserted the OnCreateUserError attribute and gave it a method named RegisterUser_CreateUserError.

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard runat="server" ID="RegisterUser" ViewStateMode="Disabled" OnCreatedUser="RegisterUser_CreatedUser" OnCreateUserError="RegisterUser_CreateUserError">
```

In the code behind, I then placed the method RegisterUser_CreateUserError:

```
    protected void RegisterUser_CreateUserError(object sender, CreateUserErrorEventArgs e)
    {
            //Error message handling here. 
    }
```

When I ran this and intentionally created a registration error (i.e. a password that did not fit the config file password requirements), the error event went to this method.